# Aligning axes which have which have aspect 'equal' with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) quite a lot for aligning my axes nicely in a plot. However, if one of the axes has `aspect=equal`, it is smaller either in height or in width. Is it possible to make the other axes have the same size than the one which was resized in order to have the correct aspect?

For example, I would like to have a layout the one below, where I have created the axes manually. The lower panel should have the same width as the upper panel which shows a matrix. How could I reproduce this with gridspec?

What I would like to reproduce with gridspec:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the figure
figx, figy = 8.0, 7.0
ratio = figx/figy
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figx, figy))  # h, v

# size of the panels
upper_height = 0.49 # width of square is determined by its height
lower_height = 0.25 # lower width is same as square height
cax_width = 0.04 # cax_height is same as square height
w_pad = 0.03
h_pad = 0.080
pad = 0.096
left = 0.30

# the lower panel
l, b, w, h = left, pad, upper_height/ratio, lower_height
ax_lower = fig.add_axes([l, b, w, h])

# calculate ax l, b, w, h 
l, b, w, h = left, pad + lower_height+h_pad, upper_height/ratio, upper_height
ax_upper = fig.add_axes([l, b, w, h])

# and cax
l, b, w, h = left + upper_height/ratio + w_pad, pad + lower_height+h_pad, cax_width, upper_height
cax = fig.add_axes([l, b, w, h])

# data
data = np.random.rand(6,6)

# show the matrix
m = ax_upper.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.gray, origin="lower")
cb = plt.colorbar(m, cax=cax)

# sum over the columns in the lower plot
ax_lower.plot(np.sum(data, axis=0), "kx")
ax_lower.set_xlim(-0.5, 5.5)
ax_lower.set_title("sum over columns")

plt.show()
```